# Passing object key as javascript function argument

Tags: javascript, object, parameters, arguments, key-value

I have an object, op_hours, which has days of the week as keys from mon - sun, with arrays of strings as values (In my actual code the values are arrays of objects, but I have changed them to strings here for simplicity).

How may I add/remove strings from a certain key by passing the required key into a function argument?

For instance,

```
function add(somethingToAdd, op_hours, key) {
  var sample = op_hours.key;
  sample.push(somethingToAdd);
  op_hours.key = sample;
  return op_hours;
}

var op_hours = {

  "mon": ["apple","orange"],
  "tue": ["table", "chair"],
  "wed": ["shark", "dolphin", "jellyfish"],
  "thu": [],
  "fri": [],
  "sat": [],
  "sun": []
};
```

I currently have to write 14 functions, seven for adding and seven for deleting as follows:

```
function addMon(miniObj, bigObj) {
  var sample = bigObj.mon;
  sample.push(miniObj);
  bigObj.mon = sample;
  return bigObj;
}}
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar, that link is similar to what I'm asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access a specific key with the array notation:

```
op_hours[key].push('shark')
```

where `key === "thu"` for example

would give you:

```
 op_hours = {

  "mon": ["apple","orange"],
  "tue": ["table", "chair"],
  "wed": ["shark", "dolphin", "jellyfish"],
  "thu": ["shark"],
  "fri": [],
  "sat": [],
  "sun": []
}
```